# Float right do not go all the way up in presence of float left elements

Tags: css, css-float

I have arranged my blocks in dom, in order i want them on smaller viewports, but i can not figure out how to make block 5 to go up next to block 3 on larger screens. Blocks will not be fixed height in my implementation.

See my pen, i hope it explains what i am up to.

http://codepen.io/pirksts/pen/MyjBmP

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="block block--right">1</div>
    <div class="block block--left">2</div>
    <div class="block block--left">3</div>
    <div class="block block--left">4</div>
    <div class="block block--right">
        5. Why I dont go to next to block 3 ??
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 400px;
    background-color: gray;
    padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
}
.block {
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
}
.block--left {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
}
.block--right {
    float: right;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: 5 floats next to the nearest div, which is 4, not 3

Comment: Just change position on number 4 and 5? 
As @silviagreen said it floats to the nearest div, it can't float past another element.

Comment: Yes, its obvious, i just hope there is a work around for this, that is why i am posting. If not, I will change dom order with JS to get what i want. I am posting to find css-only alternatives to make block 5 to go up next to block 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed a wrapper for 2,3,4 and float it as one big block, not all blocks separately, here is the answer http://codepen.io/pirksts/pen/mPrzPo

```
See <div class="main-info">
```